# How to configure jquery.mmenu to only display the iconbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, mmenu

How i configure jquery.mmenu to display only the iconbar on the page.
the https://mmenu.frebsite.nl/ does what i need, but i could not figure out how they did it.
When I load the page, I want to display only the icon bar, then when I click the icon bar it shows the menu. when I click a menu, the page reload and show only the icon bar.
I tried to set offCanvas to false, and it hides also the icon bar
When I set offCanvas to true it shows the entire menu.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that a can solve it by defining a higher value for min-width in the sidebar > expanded option like below:

```
sidebar: {
        collapsed: {
            use: '(min-width: 250px)',
            size: 40,
            hideNavbar: false
        },
        expanded: {
            use: '(min-width: 1600px)',
            size: 35
        }
    },
```

this keep the menu closed for a normal screen width